# What is the URL of the Cloud Firestore console within the Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a program with Android Studio (JAVA). I'm developing a card manager app that use firebase database and authentication.

I'm looking for the URL of realtime database.
It's the first time that I use Firebase services and I'm new in this context. I read that I can find it in the main page of the database but I can't find it.

Can you help me please? without that I can proceed.

[image: Which is the key?]

Comment: Your question says you're using Firebase Realtime Database, but your screenshot is showing Cloud Firestore.  They are completely different database products.

Comment: About what URL are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{YOUR PROJECT NAME HERE}/database
Under the realtime Database tab you will see its URL.